# How to solve The argument type 'Uint8List?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Uint8List'

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

How to solve this error. I have put a sign ! on those errors but still not able to solve the error. Can someone help me?

Code:

```
Uint8List? complaintSketch;
 Uint8List? bodyDiagramSketch;
 Uint8List? rightHeadDiagramSketch;                                                                     
 Uint8List? leftHeadDiagramSketch;
 
 await Printing.layoutPdf(
       onLayout: (PdfPageFormat format) async =>
       (await generatePatientConsultationDocument(
       format, 
       setupProfile, 
       'medical', 
       complaintSketch.isDefinedAndNotNull ? complaintSketch : null, 
       bodyDiagramSketch.isDefinedAndNotNull ? bodyDiagramSketch : null, 
       rightHeadDiagramSketch.isDefinedAndNotNull ? rightHeadDiagramSketch : null, 
       leftHeadDiagramSketch.isDefinedAndNotNull ? leftHeadDiagramSketch : null)).save());
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `layoutPdf` function expects non-null parameters. If you have nullable variables, you need to coerce them. The easiest way would be something like:

```
complaintSketch.isDefinedAndNotNull ? complaintSketch! : defaultValue,
```

You will also need to provide a value in case they are null, because `null` is not acceptable for the function.

Ideally you would also want to avoid the null-safety bypass (`!`) by properly handling the null cases.

The simplest way would be to do:

```
complaintSketch ?? defaultValue,
```

That is type safe and doesn't even need your `isDefinedAndNotNull` function.

If you don't have default values, then you cannot generate the PDF. In that case, you can make your function itself return null, and add checks for each nullable argument:

```
if (complaintSketch == null) {
    return null;
}
// ...

return await Printing.layoutPdf(
    // ...
    complaintSketch, // this will work now
);
```